# How to copy only values in excel vba from a range?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I'm trying to copy values from a table to a Range, in Excel using vba Macros, but I dont want the table format, only its values.  How can I achieve this?

Here is part of the code:

```
    'Source range
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1")

    'Destination range
    Set dest = Range(.Cells(linhaAtual, 1), .Cells(linhaAtual + r.Rows.Count - 1, 5))

    r.Copy Destination:= dest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve a solution that works.

There follows the code:

```
    Set r = Sheets("Criteria").Range("CriteriaTable")

    Set dest = Range(.Cells(linhaAtual, 1), .Cells(linhaAtual + r.Rows.Count - 1, 5))
    Sheets("Criteria").Activate
    r.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Load").Activate
    dest.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 7):

You can skip the copy command altogether by assigning the values of the source range to your destination range:

```
'Source range
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1")
'Destination range
Set dest = Range(.Cells(linhaAtual, 1), .Cells(linhaAtual + r.Rows.Count - 1, 5))

dest.Value = r.Value
```

Comment: I tried this but it show me other problem. I was using values like ''value 1'. Using this technique when the value was copied it became 'value 1', disapearing the first "'" character. Not what I want, it should be exactly the same value.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for the functionality of pasting values. You can record it, or use what I have done below. (from recording so selecting is in there, which will make it run slower, but you aren't looping so it is only constant time being added).

```
Selection.Copy
        'Select your destination like range("destination").select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If I provided the best answer for you, selecting my answer by clicking the check mark would be of great benefit to me! I am just starting out on this site and getting the initial reputation is important! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to copy from "Sheet1" to "Sheet1" - of course you can make this a parameter and loop through all your sheets

```
Dim rSource as range 'Source Range
Dim rDest as range   'Target Range - It should be the same dimension
Dim wbSource as workbook 'Source Workbook
Dim wbTarget as workbook 'Target Workbook
Dim myRange as string

myRange = "A:G" ' It is an example, you can make it dynamic

'add new workbook
    Workbooks.Add
    Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook

'Set the Source Range
    Set rSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(myRange)

'Destination Range
    Set rDest = wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(myRange)

'Copy values only
    rSource.Copy
    rDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the pastespecial command as shown below.

```
'Source range
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1")

'Destination range
Set dest = Range(.Cells(linhaAtual, 1), .Cells(linhaAtual + r.Rows.Count - 1, 5))

r.Copy 
dest.pastespecial paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Range.Value method.  Its like setting a `variable a = 1`.  Where you think of it as copying 1 to a. So...

```
Range2.value = Range1.value
```

or

```
Worksheets("historical").Range("A1:F15").Value =  Worksheets("actuals").Range("A1:F15").Value
```

Here I'm copying some data in worksheet actual to some historical worksheet.  Or if you prefer **setting** the value of one range to another range.

Answer (score 0):

```
r.Copy
dest.pastespecial xlPastevalues
```

Comment: Instead of just posting a code fragment, you should expand your answer to explain what you're doing and why it answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the copy command altogether as MP24 said .. his suggestion worked for me  after modifyibg the last line from **"value"** to **"formula"** as follows

> Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1")
> Set dest = Range(.Cells(linhaAtual, 1), .Cells(linhaAtual +
> r.Rows.Count - 1, 5))
>
> **dest.formula** = **r.formula**