# VBA: Copy and paste values in next empty row in other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a range from "Sheet1" and pasting values, not code, to the next empty row in "Sheet2". I have found this code but it only copys and pastes code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G32:I54").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) 'Select Case Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = ""
```

Can anyone help pasting values and not code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy only values in excel vba from a range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294923/how-to-copy-only-values-in-excel-vba-from-a-range)

Comment: No, not really because it does not concider placing at first empty cell

Comment: This is most definitely a duplicate. The answers to that other question are applicable to your case; just substitute your range (`End(xlUp)` and all that jazz) for the other question's `dest`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G32:I54").Copy 
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).pastespecial paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).pastespecial paste:=xlPasteValues
application.cutcopymode=false
```

Comment: If I uses this I just get the error 'This operationrequires the merged cells to be identically sized'. Which part of the second line is considering the size of the cells?

Comment: You need to apply the formats first, I believe. Try now.

Comment: Still same error occurs. It pastes formats but gives error at line 3