# Copy/Paste Values to hold formula answers

Tags: excel, vba

So this is my VBA that is currently working for coping a formula and pasting it into a set of cells that moves down each day.    I am missing the part at the end where it then copies the same set of cells and paste back into the same cells as values so that the values stay for the next day.  Thanks in advance for the help. :)

```
Sub Cash()

Dim rng_Copy As Range
Dim rng_Paste As Range

Set rng_Copy = Sheet1.Range("$M$1")
Set rng_Paste = Range("G" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

rng_Copy.Copy
rng_Paste.Resize(18, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy only values in excel vba from a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294923/how-to-copy-only-values-in-excel-vba-from-a-range)

Comment: I am trying all the answers i am seeing and it isn't working. :(   i am very new to VBA.

Comment: my problem is that my range drops down each day to fill the next 18 cells in column G so my row numbers don't stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would adding

```
rng_Paste.Copy
rng_Paste.Resize(18, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

to the bottom of your code accomplish what you're looking for? This will convert the formulas you just pasted down into values.