# VBA excel macro to copy only values of a file

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to create a code in VBA that takes each tab of an excel files and paste everything in another file keeping the same formatting but without formulas (only values). Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: [`Range.PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial), or [value transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294923/how-to-copy-only-values-in-excel-vba-from-a-range), should be helpful here.

Comment: you need to clarify more. Do you want to just copy each tab and place it into a workbook that is already made? Do you want each tab to copy over or do you want just the data in each tab to paste into 1 tab in a different workbook?

Comment: Have a look at this, edit it to suit your needs, I looked at several answers posted on here to get what I wanted... So see> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768023/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike - I generally try to suggest using the cell properties instead of copy/paste. `targetRange. Value = sourceRange.Value`, `targetRange.Font.Bold = sourceRange.Font.Bold`, etc. Copy/paste mucks with the user's clipboard.

Comment: @SmileyFtW Well, I am not a programmer and my target is to get it to work - it did and still does when I have 400 student exams to mark. So any suggestions for improvement are welcome.