C# using interop, copying an Excel sheet into another one (values only)
Need to copy from one sheet in a workbook by specifying the range, to another sheet in another workbook but if the column contains a formula I just want to get the value in my second sheet.
Here's the code I'm using :
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;

Workbook FichierCE = app.Workbooks.Open(currentFileTravail,UpdateLinks:true);
Worksheet fichierTab = FichierCE.Worksheets[tabCEEntiteName];
Workbook wBFichierTab = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet fichierTabTab = wBFichierTab.Worksheets[1];

Range data = fichierTab.Range["A4:B100"];
data.Copy(fichierTabTab.Range["A1"]);

Some of the formulas are off by some lines since they come from other sheets in the first file, so to avoid all this i just want to copy the calculated value
Thank you

Does your code work? Are you having a specific problem? Do you just want someone to provide you with working code?  If the latter, that's not how ti's site works

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52707255/34092

The code works, but the results are not good, some values are off by some lines

The general solution for this task is to copy the whole sheet first then copy values only. This method preserves sheet and cells formatting.
To copy values from the source sheet, use the 'Worksheet.UsedRange' property to operate with the occupied area of the worksheet.
A good sample is here.

Thank you @rotabor, it did help.
I didn't have to copy the entire worksheet, I used the code that I'll list in the next post.

I finally used @rotabor's answer to build mine without having to copy the whole worksheet.
Code is as follows :
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                app.Visible = true;

                Workbook FichierCE = app.Workbooks.Open(currentFileTravail,UpdateLinks:true);
                Worksheet fichierTab = FichierCE.Worksheets[tabCEEntiteName];
                Workbook wBFichierTab = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
                
                Worksheet fichierTabTab = wBFichierTab.Worksheets[1];
                                    
                fichierTabTab.Name = tabCEEntiteName; 

                Range data = fichierTab.UsedRange;
                int rows = data.Rows.Count;
                //int cols = data.Columns.Count;

                for (int r = 4; r <= rows; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 1; c <= 2; c++)
                    {
                        if (data.Cells[r, c].Value2 == null)
                        {
                            fichierTabTab.Cells[r - 3, c] = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fichierTabTab.Cells[r - 3, c] = data.Cells[r, c].Value2.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }

I just needed the first 2 columns and only the rows starting from row 4
